# DRF Model with foreign key to a field which is itself a ManyToMany field in another model

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a requirement where I want to have 3 models.

1. Member
2. Group
3. Expense

The Member model would have just one field i.e.

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

The Groups model would have 2 fields i.e.

```
group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
group_members = models.ManyToManyField(Member)
```

The Expense Model would have the below fields i.e.

```
amount_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
group_name = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
paid_by = 
paid_for =
```

How should my paid_by and paid_for be designed in the model such that I can see only the member entries based on the group name selected in the DRF form.

**For e.g.**

**I have 4 members:**
Member1
Member2
Member3
Member4

The group **Group1** has **Member1, Member2 and Member3** in it.

Now if I select **Group1** for first expense entry, I should be able to select one of the values from **Member1, Member2 and Member3** for **paid_by** field. **Member4** should not be allowed as its not part of Group1. Also, for **paid_for** field I should be able to select multiple values out of **Member1, Member2 and Member3**.

Could someone please help how to design the model and serializer for this?

**Edit: How should the below be changed to achieve this?**

````
from django.db import models


class Member(models.Model):
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.member_name


class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    member = models.ManyToManyField(Member, related_name='group_member')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name


class Expense(models.Model):
    group_name = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paid_by = models.OneToOneField(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paid_for = models.ManyToManyField(Member, related_name='paid_for')
    amount_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)```
````

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
class Member(models.Model):
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.member_name


class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    member = models.ManyToManyField(Member, related_name='group_member')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name


class Expense(models.Model):
    group_name = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paid_by = models.OneToOneField(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paid_for = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: Thanks.. but won't this allow any of the values inserted into the Members model to be selected, rather than only allowing those members who are part of a particular group..? E.g only allow those members part of Group1 to be selected for the fields paid_by and paid_for.

Comment: oh i forget about that consideration you should change paid_for = models.ForeignKey(Groups)

Comment: if you got your answer you can accept the answer could help for others in future

Comment: I am still not clear with the answer. See my EDIT in the original question. Any idea how that should be changed in order to achieve the desired result?

Comment: you cant directly use paid_for for the member outside the group so paid_for should be foreign key in my understanding

Comment: once check updated answer does it satisfy your model

Comment: So, this allows us to select one of the members for the paid_by field of Expense model whereas we only need to allow one of the members of the Group to be selected for the paid_by field. Also, for paid_for field, this takes the whole group which was paid for, whereas there needs to be capability to select a subset of members of the group for which the expense was incurred.

Comment: In general, the scenario is lets say there are 4 friends and 3 of the friends went on a trip so the group name is **Trip**. There is some food that one of the friends wanted to buy for himself but he didn't have the money to pay for it. Hence one of the friends from the group of 3 who went for the trip pays for it and becomes paid_by and the friend for whom the food was bought becomes the paid for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225234/discussion-between-daneil-james-and-codecrazy46).